# Using \NewDocumentCommand with arguments

Tags: macros

With the following function, how can I define `\NewDocumentCommand` to use
`\piston_lvsm:n` ?

```
\cs_new_protected:Nn \piston_lvsm:n
  { \setlength \smallskipamount{#1} }
```

Would it be like this ?

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\lsvm}{m}
  {
    \piston_lvsm:n {#1}
  }
```

Comment: your question doesn't make sense. You can't "define" `\NewDocumentCommand`, it is already defined and if you change it you will break lots of packages.

Comment: Do you mean: Define a *new document command* **using** `\NewDocumentCommand` which in the end uses `\piston_lvsm:n`?

Comment: To use `\NewDocumentCommand` to call `\piston_lvsm:n` taking a single argument.

Comment: Previously I used to have a command taking single argument defined using `\newcommand`.

Comment: look up the documentation of \NewDocumentCommand in usrguide (or search here, you will find lots of questions and answers).

Comment: "Would it be like this?" Have you tested that approach out?  Does it work?  Does it give you an error?

Comment: "Would it be like this?" Don't you test your code/macros with a test run on a simple document?

Comment: @Teepeemm two persons, same thought... :)

Comment: Well I would use `\lvsm` (and not `\lsvm`) for the outer command to match the inner name.

Comment: `usrguide` does not discuss `\NewDocumentCommand`

Comment: @Veak If you have an up-to-date LaTeX install it does, see e.g. the release on CTAN: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/usrguide.pdf

Comment: If I understand well what you want to do: `\protected\def\lsvm#1{\smallskipamount=#1\relax}`. You need not any LaTeX3 specialities. You can only get it by TeX primitives, which is much more simple and straightforward.

Comment: I have version of TexLive of 2022.

Comment: Yes, but now I am starting to use `expl3`.

Comment: Sometimes I do not see the name within braces  `\NewDocumentCommand{\lsvm}{m}` but  `\NewDocumentCommand \lsvm {m}`.

Comment: I recommend you to start to use TeX and primarily TeX primitives, no expl3. It is much more simple.

Comment: @wipet With all due respect, it's simpler for you because you've mastered TeX. It's not simpler for us mere mortals ;).

Comment: Why not just `\ExplSyntaxOn \cs_new_protected:Npn \lsvm { \setlength \smallskipamount } \ExplSyntaxOff`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking the question itself and the sub-issues from the comment thread:

- `\NewDocumentCommand\foo{m}{...}` defines a document command with one mandatory argument, which can then be passed as `#1` to underlying code
- One does not have to use `expl3` to use `\NewDocumentCommand`, or *vice versa*, although splitting document interface and code level macros is recommended
- Up to TeX Live 2022, the best place to read the docs. for `\NewDocumentCommand` is `xparse.pdf`; from TeX Live 2023 onward the core content has been moved to `usrguide.pdf`
- Braces around the macro being defined are optional: in Lamport's book, *all* arguments are given in braces, but as the command being defined (`\foo` in my example) *must* be a single token, it is reasonable to omit those

Answer (score 1):

To answer the part of your question, if it is possible, just run this code and take a look yourself ;)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \piston_lvsm:n
  { \setlength \smallskipamount{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\lsvm}{m}
  {
    \piston_lvsm:n {#1}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\smallskip
\blindtext
\lsvm{3cm}
\smallskip
\blindtext
\end{document}
```